# Full name and date - TSQL

Tags: sql

I have `table1` containing two columns:

`FirstName` and `LastName`.

I want `Full_name` (concatenation of first name and second name) in `table2` along with current date and not time.

Comment: Is missing some part of the question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
INSERT INTO table2 (fullName, todaysdate)
SELECT firstName + ' ' + lasName AS FullName,
    CONVERT(char(10), GetDate(),126)
FROM table1
```

Answer (score 0):

It's pretty simple SQL. You'll save yourself some time by reading through a few basic tutorials on the web before asking questions like this here.

Something like [this](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/default.asp) should be a good start.

```
INSERT INTO table2(
    FullName, 
    CurrentDate
 )
SELECT 
    Firstname + ' ' + LastName,
    CAST(GETDATE() AS DATE)
FROM table1
```